# JMeter - set timer after response is received

Tags: timer, jmeter

I understand that the timers in JMeter starts counting when request is sent.
I need to set the timer to start when the response is returned or times out.
Is this possible?

Comment: Was my answer ok ? If yes you should accept it if not comment, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand.

If you are talking about timers they start and end before or after a request.

Read this:

- [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#timers)
- [Scoping rules](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
- [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action)

Or maybe you are talking about response time ?